# Updating workbook link sources

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating an Excel sheet using Java code + the Apache POI library. In some of the cells, I am inserting a reference to another sheet, which will not work and display '#REF' - which is fine. The intention here is that these cells will update and display correctly once the generated sheet is moved to the actual workbook it is intended to be used in.

When moving the sheet, the cells do not update. I found out that I have to update the link sources.

I've put together some code that will grab all links, iterate them and update their source to the current open workbook.

```
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim wbDir As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbLinks As Variant
    
    wbLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    
    If (UBound(wbLinks) > 0) Then
        wbName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        wbDir = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, "\"))
        wbDir = Left(wbDir, Len(wbDir) - 1)
        wbName = Mid(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, "\") + 1)

        ChDir wbDir
        For i = 1 To UBound(wbLinks)
            ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=wbLinks(i), NewName:=wbName, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox ("No links found to update.")
    End If
```

So this is what I've tried. I recorded a macro of myself doing this manually (updating the source manually works) but even after replicating the code in VBA, it does not work.

---

Note:

Clicking the cell -> Clicking into the formula box -> Hitting enter = WORKS, no error at all.

Pressing CTRL + ALT + F9 (and with SHIFT) does not update the cells.

Two of the formulas used:

> =MASTER!B8
>
> =Management!N10

Comment: Note: If you `Dim wbName, wbDir As String` then only `wbDir` is declared as `String` but `wbName` is `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable (otherwise it is `Variant` by default): `Dim wbName As String, wbDir As String`. • Also `i` is not declared and should be `Dim i As Long`. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all variables properly.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I appreciate the tips! I made the necessary changes, but it still is not working.

Comment: Yes my comment was more as a side note (that's why I didn't post it as an answer). Do the formulas work if you enter the cell with the formula into edit mode (select cell and press F2) and then press Enter (so they get re-written)? Do you get an error message then? Can you provide the formula that results in `#REF`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've edited the original post to answer your questions. Formulas added. And if I click into the cells and hit enter after selecting the formula box, no errors at all while updating the references correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to re-write the formulas with VBA. Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) to find all formulas with error in a worksheet: `Set ErrFormulas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)`

And then loop through these to update them:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateErrorFormulas()
    Dim ErrorOccured As Boolean
    ErrorOccured = False

    Dim ErrFormulas As Range
    Set ErrFormulas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)

    If ErrFormulas Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ErrFormulas
        Cell.Formula = Cell.Formula
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this does not explain why my original code is not working - this actually solves my problem and basically replicates what I was doing manually to fix references. I am still wondering why my code doesn't work since it replicates manually updating the source... Either way, thank you!

Comment: @joe Because the workbook that the formula links to must be available when the formula gets written. You could only write the formula because you used an external library that didn't check it. Try to write a formula that links to a file that does not exist. Excel won't let you.